# Winforms custom cursor stops setting after a time

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that contains a panel. The idea is that when the mouse is hovered over the panel it displays the **OpenHand** cursor. You can then drag the panel which causes the cursor to change to the **Grab** cursor. Upon mouse release the **Grab** cursor should change back to the **OpenHand** cursor.

Unfortunately, I'm having an issue that if I drag and release my panel (with the mouse within the bounds of the panel), eventually (usually on the second or third go) the **Grab** cursor will not change back into the **OpenHand** cursor. 
This remains the case even when you move the mouse out of the panel and back in and try dragging and releasing.

Here is my Panel class:

```
public class MapPanel : Panel
{
    private Point MouseDownLocation;
    private Cursor OpenHand = new Cursor(Properties.Resources.hand.Handle);
    private Cursor Grab = new Cursor(Properties.Resources.punch.Handle);

    public MapPanel()
    {
        MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(mapPanel_MouseDown);
        MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(mapPanel_MouseUp);
        MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(mapPanel_MouseMove);
    }

    private void mapPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Cursor = Grab;
            MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
        }
    }

    private void mapPanel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
           Cursor = OpenHand;
        }
    }

    private void mapPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Left = e.X + Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
            Top = e.Y + Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
        }
    }

}
```

Interestingly there are no issues if I don't include the **MouseMove** handler, however the *Cursor = OpenHand;* statement inside the **MouseUp** method does still get called with the **MouseMove** handler included. It just doesn't take effect.

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  It works every time.  I replaced your resource cursors with just Cursors.Hand and Cursors.SizeAll.  Is there anything in the panel?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand Reza. Using the code provided I cannot move the panel without a mouse down.

Comment: I got it working. I actually found the solution on StackOverFlow. I don't know how I managed not to find it before I posted this question. Anyway, the solution is to create an Icon variable that references the custom icon to prevent the garbage collector deleting the icon. This explains why it worked for LarsTech because he didn't use his own custom icons. I have flagged the Question as a duplicate. It just awaits a moderator. I really don't understand why someone gave me a downvote as I followed MCVE standards. My rep is low and I don't want a question ban!